# Add gdebi on .deb right click?

Tags: linux, debian, package-managers, dpkg

Aside of typing "sudo gdebi-gtk", how can I add the option to open with gdebi when right-clicking on a .deb file?

I am running Debian Stretch, and Gnome.

Answer (score 1):

1-)What Desktop Environment? In Gnome the first option 'Open with GDebi Package Installer' does the trick here.

You can always install from terminal like so:

```
Code:

sudo dpkg -i packagename.deb
```

2-).deb files are installed by double left click.

They will be installed and a menu item placed in the correct menu. They usually will then appear in Add/Remove so you can uninstall if required

Comment: Ahh, thank you. I must be running into an file-association issue with 7zip.